# GitHub releases, multiple files and versioning

Tags: github, release, versioning, github-actions, semantic-versioning

If I have a GitHub repo `github.com/@product/template` with the following file/folder structure:

```
/build
  /fileA
  /fileB
/src
  /generator.sh
```

GitHub doesn't seem to be opinionated how to group file releases. There are multiple options:

**Releases with multiple files**

```
github.com/@product/template
  v1.0.0
    /fileA
    /fileB
  v1.1.0
    /fileA
    /fileB
  v1.2.0
    /fileA
    /fileB
```

**Release each file separately**

```
github.com/@product/template
  fileA-v1.0.0
    /fileA
  fileA-v1.1.0
    /fileA
  fileA-v1.2.0
    /fileA
  fileB-v1.0.0
    /fileB
  fileB-v1.1.0
    /fileB
  fileB-v1.2.0
    /fileB
```

Wondering what the advantages/disadvantages of each pattern are? Considering that files could be updated independently? fileA is updated, would that release a new version of fileB too?

Users would need to search through a longer list of releases to find the file they want to download?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> GitHub doesn't seem to be opinionated how to group file releases

True, it has no opinion: you are building your release assets as you see fit.

But: a release (for a file or multiple files) is associated to a tag (see "[creating a release](https://docs.github.com/en/free-pro-team@latest/github/administering-a-repository/managing-releases-in-a-repository)")
And that tag applies to the all source repository (to all its files in it)

That is why generally a new release includes all new deliveries.

Comment: I guess one code change could affect multiple files, so better to release all together